# AFHTTPSessionManager setting authorization header

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I've been stuck on this for a while now, I'm using Youtube's api but I keep getting a 403 error. I'm using Google Sign-in which takes care of OAuth2

```
 NSString *authToken = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[Lockbox unarchiveObjectForKey:@"accessToken"]];

 NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"mine":@"true", @"part": @"contentDetails"};
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

 manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
 [manager.requestSerializer setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSLog(@"%@----------", authToken); //Prints correct value

 [manager GET:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels" parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I know the GET url is correct because I've tried using it on OAuth 2.0 Playground and I get a 200 Response.

Below is the 403 error response I get back

```
{ status code: 403, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 356;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Sat, 17 Sep 2016 08:18:16 GMT";
Expires = "Sat, 17 Sep 2016 08:18:16 GMT";
Server = GSE;
Vary = "Origin, X-Origin";
"alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"36,35,34,33,32\"";
"x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
"x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
```

} }

I don't see the Authorization field in the headers, but I believe I set it up correctly and looked on SO for the correct way. Is there any glaring issues because I've been stuck for hours

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager

Comment: K -_-, I thought I enabled Youtube API 3 on Google but I didn't which was why I was getting a 403 forbidden access. So the code above was correct, it's just I had to enable the Youtube API. Bye I'm done with life

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/%@?alt=json",contactID];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"DELETE" URLString:string parameters:nil error:nil];
NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[[GoogleContactManager sharedManager] token]]; //bearer is my personal requirement your's can differ

[req setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[req setValue:@"3.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
[req setValue:@"*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"if-match"];
```